# Meteor route not responding

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a button to trigger my route `speaker`

`<div class='btn btn-sm' id='inspect' href="{{pathFor 'speaker'}}">inspect</div>`

The client-side js to handle the triggered route

```
Router.route('speaker', {
    path:'/speakers/:_id',
    template: 'speaker',
    data: function(){
        return Speakers.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

And a simple template to render the three fields of my data

```
<template name='speaker'>
    <h1>single speaker info</h1>
        <li>{{first}} {{last}} @ {{date}}</li>
</template>
```

But when I click my `inspect` button to trigger the route, nothing happens.  I have other routes working on my app, but I can't figure out why this one wont budge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is a div styled as a bootstrap button, but it do not retains HTML anchors (links) functionality.

What you need to do is defining an anchor and style it as a button :

```
<a class='btn btn-sm' id='inspect' href="{{pathFor 'speaker'}}">inspect</a>
```

There is also a `{{#linkTo}}` block helper in `iron:router` that you can use like this :

```
{{#linkTo class="btn btn-sm" route="speaker"}}inspect{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: how do I have bootstrap buttons in my `layout.html` that successfully trigger routes?

Comment: Unless you listen to click events on your `button` or `div` tags and use `Router.go` to mimic the purpose of an anchor (you don't want to do this BTW), this is impossible.